# Difference between GTK and Gnome

Tags: gnome, gtk-2

I am new to Linux OS. Can some body help to understand the difference between GNOME and GTK+?

Comment: Could you please re-edit your question and give more specific details to your question? GTK is a toolkit for graphics library. Gnome is, more or less a desktop environment.

Comment: This is a clear question and your comment is a clear answer. Just because the answer is obvious to you doesn't mean it deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

As [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/) GTK+3 manual says:

> GTK+ is the primary library used to construct user interfaces in GNOME
>   applications. It provides user interface controls and signal callbacks
>   to control user interfaces.